# Finding dimensional index in a multi-dimensional array in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

Am looking at say 3-dimensional array M: `M<-dim(3,3,3)`

I want to find an efficient way to populate M with the following rule: 
    *M[i,j,k] = i/10 + j^2 + sqrt(k)*, 
ideally without having to write a loop with a `for` statemenet.

For clarification, there is a simple way to accomplishing this if M were 2-dimensional. If i wanted to have 
    *M[i,j] = i/10 + j^2*, 
then i could just do
    `M<-row(M)/10 + col(M)*col(M)`

Is there something equivalent for 3-or-higher dimensional arrays?

Comment: When I read the question I thought `combn(1:3,3,foo)` with the obvious `foo`would do the job. Is there a variant of `combn` that generates all permutations?

Comment: there is certainly a way to do this with `expand.grid`, but the results would then have to be reshaped into the desired array structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@James's answer is better, but I think the narrow answer to your question (multidimensional equivalent of `row()/col()`) is `slice.index` ...

```
M<- array(dim=c(3,3,3))
slice.index(M,1)/10+slice.index(M,2)^2+sqrt(slice.index(M,3))
```

It would be a good idea if someone (I or someone else) posted a suggestion on the `r-devel` list to make `slice.index` a "See also" entry on `?row`/`?col` ...

Alternatively (similar to @flodel's new answer):

```
d <- do.call(expand.grid,lapply(dim(M),seq)) ## create data.frame of indices
v <- with(d,Var1/10+Var2^2+sqrt(Var3))       ## default names Var1, ... Varn 
dim(v) <- dim(M)                             ## reshape into array
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone. One of the problems involves crossproducts of i,j and k like Ben's *cos(i*j*k)* so seems like `slice.index` option is most elegant.

Comment: @user1766394 If you are happy with an answer provided, please consider Accepting one of them. How to do this and why it is useful is described in the [ask] section of the FAQ. To Accept, check the big tick mark next to the Answer you want to Accept.

Answer (score 4):

How about using nested `outer`s?

```
outer(1:3/10,outer((1:3)^2,sqrt(1:3),"+"),"+")
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.1  5.1 10.1
[2,]  2.2  5.2 10.2
[3,]  2.3  5.3 10.3

, , 2

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 2.514214 5.514214 10.51421
[2,] 2.614214 5.614214 10.61421
[3,] 2.714214 5.714214 10.71421

, , 3

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 2.832051 5.832051 10.83205
[2,] 2.932051 5.932051 10.93205
[3,] 3.032051 6.032051 11.03205
```

Comment: cool.  It would be neat if there were a multidimensional variant of `outer`, so that e.g. `cos(i*j*k)` would be an option, but this is a nice answer for the current case.

Comment: I suspect I'm not telling you anything that is not obvious, but maybe someone else can use this: `array( mapply(function(x,y,z) cos(x*y*z), i,j,k), c(3,3,3) )`. Refer to my much less kewl anser for i,j,and k.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `arrayInd`:

```
M   <- array(dim = c(3, 3, 3))
foo <- function(dim1, dim2, dim3) dim1/10 + dim2^2 + sqrt(dim3)
idx <- arrayInd(seq_along(M), dim(M), useNames = TRUE)
M[] <- do.call(foo, as.data.frame(idx))
```

I feel this approach has potential for less typing as the number of dimensions increases.

Comment: I _do_ like that use of arrayInd!

Answer (score 1):

Doing it from the "ground up" so to speak.

```
 i <- rep(1:3, times=3*3)
 j <- rep(1:3 , times= 3, each=3)
 k <- rep(1:3 , each= 3*3)
 M <- array( i/10 + j^2 + sqrt(k), c(3, 3, 3))
 M
```

Comment: You could also use `expand.grid` if you go that way.

Comment: And it would generalize easier to higher dimensions as well. I just wanted to demonstrate the use of the 'times' and 'each' arguments for rep. I wasn't really thinking this was a "competitive" strategy.